# Start windows 64bit driver from 32bit app on 64bit windows

Tags: c++, c, c++11, kernel, driver

Is there a work around for `StartService` in a 32bit program to start a 64bit driver on windows 64bit?

The reason i need to do it from 32bit program is that i compile the program under 32bit and 64bit depending on the type of process I'm working with.

Comment: Surely your real problem is with CreateService().  Covered well in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/3g0_49jH59M).  You need that little 64-bit helper process.

Comment: @HansPassant i just had a look at that thread, it dont really say how to create the 64bit service fro 32bit app

Comment: No, a little 64-bit helper program that calls CreateService() + StartService().  Use CreateProcess() in your 32-bit program to run it.

Comment: @HansPassant you saying the only way to do this is create a program in 64bit that gets called from my 32bit app to create the service?

Comment: That's what the Microsoft employee said.  Maybe you ought to take him seriously given that he's closest to the fountain of knowledge.

Comment: I just thought there may of been a different way to do it with creating reg keys or something, thanks for the help

Comment: You can write your service key into registry by yourself and then use NtLoadDriver to load the driver. Examine what values service keys of other drivers contain (HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<subkey>). ImagePath, Start adn Type should do the job.